# How do you use composer cli?

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, upgrade, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp v3.0.13 currently. I would like to upgrade from to v3.1.

From http://bakery.cakephp.org/2015/09/19/cakephp_3_1_0_released.html, the command to do this is;

```
php composer.phar require 'cakephp/cakephp:3.1.*' 'cakephp/debug_kit:3.2.*' 'cakephp/bake:1.1.*'
```

I tried running this command at the top folder. However, the error I got was

> Could not open input file: composer.phar

Where should I run the upgrade command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command given assumes that you've got composer installed in the local directory as a `.phar` file. If you've got composer installed globally, then the correct command would be

```
composer require 'cakephp/cakephp:3.1.*' 'cakephp/debug_kit:3.2.*' 'cakephp/bake:1.1.*'
```

If you do not have composer installed at all, then follow the relevant instructions at the composer site: https://getcomposer.org/download/